# Add row for totals at the end of each table

Tags: c#, html-table

I am looking to add a row to each of the Location's like the image below shows. The row would display the totals of each column. I have these values already calculated ( <%= owetotal %> , <%= paidtotal %>, <%= origtotal %>) just need them placed in the correct spot and I can't seem to format it the way I want it.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

My ASPX Page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            Report</h1>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span11">
                <% 
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection pcn;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand pcm;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader prs;
                    pcn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("");
                    pcm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                    pcn.Open();
                    pcm.Connection = pcn;

                    var tableSql = @"SELECT * FROM Accounts";

                    pcm.CommandText = tableSql;
                    prs = pcm.ExecuteReader();
                    var rowcount = 0;
                    var CurrentLocation = "";
                    while (prs.Read())
                    {
                        rowcount++;

                %>
                <% if (prs["Location"].ToString() != CurrentLocation)
                   { %>
                <table width="100%" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Owes
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Paid
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Original Amt
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Date
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <h4>
                        <%= prs["Location"].ToString()%></h4>

                    <% 
                        CurrentBranch = prs["Loction"].ToString();
                   } %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= prs["Name"].ToString() %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $<%= prs["Owes"].ToString() %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $<%= prs["Paid"].ToString() %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $<%= prs["OrigAmt"].ToString() %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= Convert.ToDateTime(prs["SubmitDate"].ToString()).ToShortDateString() %>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <%
                        }
                    prs.Close();
                    pcn.Close();
                    %>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are embedding all the code to do this in the aspx page?  Usually when I see this it is a bad idea...

Comment: Agreed. I would suggest putting all of the asp code in the .cs file and using a control such as GridView to display the data.

Comment: It's a small report for only two people and this was the only way I knew how to do it where it would separate out by location. I didn't want to make four different gridviews (maybe there is a way to not have to).

Comment: If you are going to take this route still, I would suggest making 4 different tables and not one big one. Also, you could do a foreach on the distinct locations and separate it out that way. You could get the list of totals based on location in your SQL. Then after you have written all the rows returned for a location you could just write an extra table row on the bottom with the total data. I think doing it this way though is probably making it harder than it would have been with gridviews.

Comment: @Tony Thanks for your input Tony, I will look into converting this to a few different gridviews instead.

Comment: Can I use one gridview for this or should I use one per location? I don't know how to separate them out by location like my screenshots show.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL statement, add

```
UNION SELECT 'Totals', sum(Owes), sum (Paid), sum(OrigAmt), '' FROM Accounts
```

Comment: I know how to get the totals I just don't know how to place them under each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You'd beteer do it in the Page_Load handler in controller. Add new row to each table and put there your Total values. And write smth about this:

```
foreach(var column in table.Columns)
{
    foreach(var field in column)
    {
        //check if it isn't last row
        //write the sum of (0..n-1) fields to lsat field in column
    }
}
```